# UIWebView vs WebView Javascript Injection

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Im trying to execute javascript on iPhone by stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString,
i made script

```
function execute() {
//dosent matter 
alert('works');
}
execute();
```

This script works fine while using in developer console in safari.

But this way :

```
[self.webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javascript:     function execute() { alert('works');}execute();"];
```

Dosent work, i dont see alert, i tried also without "javascript:"

Thats confusing because im using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString with succes but without using function declaration.

```
  [self.webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('check');"];
```

works fine

Comment: Yes, you should write your JS codes in HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for answer, i have noticed that some functions could not work properly without putting them in file.js and then execute by using:

```
- (void)injectJavascript:(NSString *)resource {
    NSString *jsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resource ofType:@"js"];
    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    [self.webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```